# MIS CHECKBOXS SE SELECCIONAN TODOS CUANDO LE DOY CLICK A UNO

Tags: flutter, dart

Muy buenas tardes o noches, necesito ayuda en un problema que tengo en flutter. Seria en los checkboxs que cuando le doy click a uno se seleccionan todos los checkboxs y yo quisiera que funcione normal como cualquier checkbox que al darle click se seleccione al que le di click. Gracias de antemano ojala puedan ayudarme

**ESTE SERIA EL API**

```
Future<List<UiOption>?> uiOptionGetByApplicationId(GetByIdRequest request) async {
    final mapResponse = await dialer(
        Uri.http(
            _urlAuthorization, "api/authorization/UiOptionGetByApplicationId"),
        request.toJson());

    var result = UiOptionGetByApplicationIdResponse.fromJson(mapResponse);

    return result.data;
}
```

**ESTE SERIA LA CLASE QUE USO**

```
class UiOption {
  int? id;
  int? applicationId;
  String? code;
  String? description;
  String? type;
  String? classs;
  String? url;
  int? state;
  String? action;
  bool? done;

  UiOption({
    this.id = 0,
    this.applicationId = 0,
    this.code = "",
    this.description = "",
    this.type = "",
    this.classs = "",
    this.url = "",
    this.state = 0,
    this.action = "",
  }) : done = false;
}
```

**ESTE SERIA EL CODIGO COMPLETO**

Aqui va el propiedad Checkbox y creo que es donde esta el error pero no logro encontrarlo. Por cierto tenfo el nullsafety.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_4/src/dto/getByIdRequest.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import '../dto/metaRequest.dart';
import '../models/uiOption.dart';
import '../providers/seguridad_provider.dart';
import 'widgets/menuDesplegable.dart';

const PrimaryColor = const Color(0xFF5382A3);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: UiOptionRolPage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class UiOptionRolPage extends StatefulWidget {
  UiOptionRolPage({Key? key, this.title, this.idAppli}) : super(key: key);
  final String? title;
  final int? idAppli;
  @override
  _UiOptionRolPageState createState() => _UiOptionRolPageState();
}

class _UiOptionRolPageState extends State<UiOptionRolPage> {
  Future<List<UiOption>?> uiOptionGetByApplicationId() async {
    var applicationid = widget.idAppli;
    var meta = new MetaRequest(
        modifier: "FLUTTER",
        currentPage: 0,
        size: 0,
        identifier: Uuid().v1().toString());

    var request = new GetByIdRequest(id: applicationid, meta: meta);

    return await SecurityProvider().uiOptionGetByApplicationId(request);
  }

  @override
  String _nombre = '';
  bool? _checked = false;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
        title: (Text('Rol/Aplicativo/UI')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          BackButton(),
          IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: () => print('Boton 3 puntos'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<UiOption>?>(
            future: uiOptionGetByApplicationId(),
            builder: (context, data) {
              if (data.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting &&
                  data.hasData) {
                var userList = data.data;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userList!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _checked = !_checked!;
                            });
                          },
                          child: ListTile(
                            key: Key("$index"),
                            trailing: Checkbox(
                              value: _checked,
                              onChanged: (checked) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _checked = checked;
                                });
                              },
                              activeColor: PrimaryColor,
                            ),
                            title: Text(userList[index].description ?? ""),
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              child: Text(
                                  userList[index].description!.substring(0, 1)),
                              backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ));
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: MainDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ESTE ES EL RESULTADO QUE SALE AL DAR CLICK A UN CHECKBOX**

[image: Al dar click a un checkbox se seleccionan todos y cuando le doy click de nuevo se deseleccionan todos]

Comment: Tal vez esta respuesta te pueda ayudar!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790054/multiple-checkbox-in-flutter-from-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que crear un nuevo widget en donde poner el estado de cada checkbox. Tu codigo quedaria algo asi

```
class _UiOptionRolPageState extends State<UiOptionRolPage> {
  Future<List<UiOption>?> uiOptionGetByApplicationId() async {
    var applicationid = widget.idAppli;
    var meta = new MetaRequest(
        modifier: "FLUTTER",
        currentPage: 0,
        size: 0,
        identifier: Uuid().v1().toString());

    var request = new GetByIdRequest(id: applicationid, meta: meta);

    return await SecurityProvider().uiOptionGetByApplicationId(request);
  }

  @override
  String _nombre = '';

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
        title: (Text('Rol/Aplicativo/UI')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          BackButton(),
          IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: () => print('Boton 3 puntos'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<UiOption>?>(
            future: uiOptionGetByApplicationId(),
            builder: (context, data) {
              if (data.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting &&
                  data.hasData) {
                var userList = data.data;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userList!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        UiOptionWidget(index, userList[index]));
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: MainDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UiOptionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final UiOption uiOption;

  const UiOptionWidget(this.index, this.uiOption);

  @override
  _UiOptionWidgetState createState() => _UiOptionWidgetState();
}

class _UiOptionWidgetState extends State<UiOptionWidget> {
  bool? _checked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _checked = !_checked!;
        });
      },
      child: ListTile(
        key: Key("${widget.index}"),
        trailing: Checkbox(
          value: _checked,
          onChanged: (checked) {
            setState(() {
              _checked = checked;
            });
          },
          activeColor: PrimaryColor,
        ),
        title: Text(widget.uiOption.description ?? ""),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text(widget.uiOption.description!.substring(0, 1)),
          backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yayo era justo lo que necesitaba te lo agradezco.